# Extensions Manager returns "Internal Server Error"

Tags: control-panel, ee1, extension

An EE1 site that I developed many years ago was recently moved to a new server. I logged into the CP to do some work and everything seemed fine, but when I tried to pull up "Utilities -> Extensions Manager", I get an "Internal Server Error".

I FTP'd in, and everything seems to be in place, permissions correct, etc. Is there something specific that I should look for?

Answer (score 1):

It could be any number of things, PHP memory limit, PHP version change (this would be my guess), .htaccess

If you've moved server then it's most likely running a newer version of PHP and if I remember rightly EE1 won't work past a certain PHP version.

I'd compare the versions, check the difference in memory and perhaps temporarily remove the htaccess file.